# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource in AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I am new in "AWS" server,Whenever i am trying to access "phpmyadmin" then i am getting following error

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource
```

How can i solve this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you think that would work?  What setup had you done?  What operating system are you running?  You've given us virtually nothing here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided enough information for us to assist you. Please let us know what you did when this error appeared. It appears to be an error message from a web browser? If so, it means that URL you entered is not responding. What URL did you use?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My current url is 
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/phpmyadmin

Comment: When you enter that URL, are you entering it on your own computer, or a remote computer? What is the URL pointing to -- for example, is it pointing to an Amazon EC2 instance where you have installed MySQL? Why do you think it should work?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i dont know much about this because i am new in aws, kindly explain what should i do

Comment: You are attempting to go to a URL in your web browser. Where did you get the URL? Where does that URL point to?